# How to use the date-formatter of bootstrap-table in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-table

Hello, I am using the bootstrap-table library with an Angular4. But using date-formatter does not bring me any value.

code html:

```
<table id="table" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                                            <th data-field="userId" data-sortable="true">Usuario</th>
                                            <th data-field="userName" data-sortable="true">Nombre</th>
                                            <th data-field="lastName" data-sortable="true">Apellido</th>
                                            <th data-field="email" data-sortable="true">Correo</th>
                                            <th data-field="mobilePhone">Teléfono</th>
                                            <th data-field="cargo">Cargo</th>
                                            <th data-field="evento" data-formatter="acciones">Eventos</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                </table>
```

code typescript:

```
  tableRow(data){
    $(function () {
        $('#table').bootstrapTable({
            data: data,
            pagination: true,
            pageNumber: 1,
            pageSize: 10,
            search: true,
            minimumCountColumns: 2,
            iconsPrefix : 'icon',
            icons: {
              refresh: 'ion-ios-loop-strong',
              toggle: 'ion-ios-list-outline',
              columns: 'ion-ios-more'
            }
        });
    });
    function acciones(){
      return "<a href='/user:id' />Edit</a>";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `acciones` is only defined in the typescript function `tableRow`.

`bootstrap-table`'s `data-formatter` seems to use global functions (i.e. defined in `window`).

This should work :

```
window.acciones = function () {
  return '<a href="/user:id">Edit</a>';
};
```

---

NOTE: I don't think `bootstrap-table` is compatible with `Angular`. I wouldn't recommend to use a `jQuery` plugin in this kind of environment.

Comment: Hello Ludovic, Adjust the code, but it did not work.

Comment: Which library do you recommend for Angular 4 tables?

Comment: Sorry then, I think `bootstrap-table` will not find your method due to closures. This plugin is not provided for Angular4.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview or https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable

Comment: PrimeNG is probably more complete than Material (if you look at the other widgets).

Comment: To use primeNg do I need to have a primefaces project?

Comment: No, you just have to install the npm dependency as described in the getting started guide.

Comment: Thanks..  going to try